# Java Script function not working?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm using this codes below but seems my setValue() method is not working. can someone point what is wrong with this codes?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script language="javascript"> 
function rand ( n )
{
    document.getElementById("orderRefId").value =  ( Math.floor ( Math.random ( ) * n + 1 ) );
}

function setValue(amount1)
{
    myValue = amount1;
    document.getElementById("amount").value = myValue;
  }


</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="rand( 2000000 )">
        <!-- 
            Note: https://www.pesopay.com/b2c2/eng/payment/payForm.jsp for live payment URL
                  https://test.pesopay.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp for test payment URL
        -->
        <form method="POST" name="frmPayment" action="https://test.pesopay.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp">
        <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Order Reference No. (your reference number for every transaction that has transpired):</td> 
            <td><input type="text" id="orderRefId" name="orderRef" value="Test-001"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Amount:</td>
            <td><input type="text" onLoad = "setValue()" name="amount" value=""/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Currency Code - "608" for Philippine Peso, "840" for US Dollar:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="currCode" value="608"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Language:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lang" value="E"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Merchant ID (the merchant identification number that was issued to you - merchant IDs between test account and live account are not the same):</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="merchantId" value="18056869"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Redirect to a URL upon failed transaction:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="failUrl" value="http://www.yahoo.com?flag=failed"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Redirect to a URL upon successful transaction:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="successUrl" value="http://www.google.com?flag=success"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Redirect to a URL upon canceled transaction:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cancelUrl" value="http://www.altavista.com?flag=cancel"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Type of payment (normal sales or authorized i.e. hold payment):</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="payType" value="N"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Payment Method - Change to "ALL" for all the activated payment methods in the account, Change to "BancNet" for BancNet debit card payments only, Change to "GCASH" for GCash mobile payments only, Change to "CC" for credit card payments only:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="payMethod" value="ALL"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Remark:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="remark" value="Asiapay Test"/></td>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr>    
            <td>Redirect:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="redirect" value="1"/></td>
        </tr>-->
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>   

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

NOTE: the variable "amount1" is came from my android. and its not causing the problem because I'm using it in other codes.

I will be very thankful for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.You don't have no DOMInputElement with id "amount". You need to change the html like this:

```
<input type="text" onLoad = "setValue()" name="amount" id="amount" value=""/>
```

Or the js like this:

```
function setValue(amount1)
{
    myValue = amount1;
    document.frmPayment.amount.value = myValue;
}
```

2.The second issue is that you cannot attach the onLoad event to input element. What you can do, is put the <script/> with setValue() call or change your <body> tag to:

```
<body onLoad="rand(200000);setValue();">
```

Comment: I already tried both what you said but still not working for me.

Comment: ^^ works for me, you can try also: document.forms['frmPayment'].amount.value = myValue;   (but it will do the same)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is in the default settings disabled in the WebView. You need to activate it first.

```
YourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

---

You also need to correct your JavaScript. You call the function `document.getElementById(...)`, but your input element has no Id but a name. So you need to call `document.getElementsByName(...)[0]`.

Comment: I had this code in my class    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

```
           function text() {
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.format("dd-mmm-yyyy");
        var newdt = dt.getFullYear();
        var tt = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPolicyStartDate").value;           
        var dt2 = new Date.parseLocale(tt, 'dd-MMM-yyyy');     

        dt2.setFullYear(dt2.getFullYear() + 1);
        dt2.setDate(dt2.getDate() - 1);
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPolicyExpiryDate").value = dt2.format("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        return dt2;
    }
```